# Shiny plot shows up in RStudio window instead of in browser

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

If you run the following code in RStudio, it correctly shows two plots, but if you make a small change (detailed below), it no longer shows the second plot.

(Note that `examplePathways` and `exampleRanks` are provided by the fgsea package so the following code should be runnable as is.)

```
library(fgsea)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("gseaPlot"),
  plotOutput("gseaEnrichment")
)

runAnalysis <- function() {
  gseaResult <- fgsea(pathways = examplePathways, stats = exampleRanks, nperm = 10)
  topPathways <- gseaResult[NES > 0][head(order(desc(NES)), n = 10), pathway]
  topPathwayUp <- topPathways[[1]]
  gseaEnrichment <- plotEnrichment(examplePathways[[topPathwayUp]], exampleRanks)
  gseaPlot <- plotGseaTable(examplePathways[topPathways], exampleRanks, gseaResult)
  list(gseaEnrichment = gseaEnrichment, gseaPlot = gseaPlot)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  theAnalysis <- runAnalysis()
  output$gseaEnrichment <- renderPlot({
    theAnalysis$gseaEnrichment
  })
  output$gseaPlot <- renderPlot({
    runAnalysis()$gseaPlot
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The small change is that if I change the second renderPlot to use `theAnalysis` instead of `runAnalysis()`, like so:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  theAnalysis <- runAnalysis()
  output$gseaEnrichment <- renderPlot({
    theAnalysis$gseaEnrichment
  })
  output$gseaPlot <- renderPlot({
    theAnalysis$gseaPlot
  })
}
```

then suddenly the second plot shows up in the RStudio viewer window instead of in the browser.

What is going on here to cause this behavior and how can I fix it without resorting to running `runAnalysis()` twice?

UPDATE: Actually, the following displays the problem even more simply and doesn't involve Shiny. If I run the following code, the plot shows up in the RStudio plot viewer, even though it's been stored to a variable (but the same is not true of plotEnrichment):

```
library(dplyr)
library(fgsea)
library(ggplot2)
gseaResult <- fgsea(pathways = examplePathways, stats = exampleRanks, nperm = 10)
topPathways <- gseaResult[NES > 0][head(order(desc(NES)), n = 10), pathway]
gseaPlot <- plotGseaTable(examplePathways[topPathways], exampleRanks, gseaResult)
```

UPDATE: Apparently this does not happen with fgsea version 1.6 (I'm using version 1.8), so it may be a bug in fgsea, so I've submitted an issue with fgsea. But I welcome answers if anyone can see the problem or has a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by the fact that `plotGseaTable` was calling `grid.arrange`, which renders to the current device. That is why running it directly from the reactive context worked, whereas running it outside of the reactive context did not.

The solution is to have `plotGseaTable` return the grob and then render it within the reactive context, like this:

```
library(grid)

...

runAnalysis <- function() {
  ...
  # The render = FALSE here (not yet available in fgsea)
  # which allows the plot to be rendered later
  gseaPlot <- plotGseaTable(examplePathways[topPathways], exampleRanks, gseaResult, render = FALSE)
  ...
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  theAnalysis <- runAnalysis()
  output$gseaEnrichment <- renderPlot({
    theAnalysis$gseaEnrichment
  })
  output$gseaPlot <- renderPlot({
    grid.draw(theAnalysis$gseaPlot)
  })
}
```

A pull request was made to fgsea to allow this for plotGseaTable: https://github.com/ctlab/fgsea/pull/43.